# How to convert the list to glob style pattern in python

Tags: python, design-patterns, glob, copytree

I need to copy the files using shutil copytree with certain pattern. The patterns I am having as list. I converted the list to string using below method to pass in the copy tree ignore_pattern as below.

```
def convert_list_to_str(pattern):
    patter = ','.join("'{0}'".format(x) for x in pattern)
    return patter

copytree(sourcedir, target_dir,ignore=ignore_patterns(pattr))
```

If I hard code the pattern as below

```
copytree(sourcedir, target_dir,ignore=ignore_patterns('*.bat','*.jar'))
```

It is working fine, Here I cannot iterate the pattern because in first run it will create the folder. So I need to convert the list to glob pattern so that it can be passed as a parameter. But don't know how to convert the list to glob pattern.

How to achieve this?

**EDIT:**

```
aa = ['*.bat','*.txt']
print(convert_list_to_str(aa))
```

Result:

```
'*.bat','*.txt'
```

Comment: what are the inputs to `convert_list_to_str`, what does it return, and what do you want it to return?

Comment: Can you print your patterns?

Comment: See my edits @thebjorn and ThatBird

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need your list_to_str function. When it says `ignore_patterns(*patterns)` in the docs it means that the function takes zero or more arguments. So you need to call it like this:

```
copytree(sourcedir, target_dir,ignore=ignore_patterns(*pattern))
```

notice the `*` before pattern, it converts your list to a series of arguments.

You can read more about the unpack operator(s) in python here: https://codeyarns.com/2012/04/26/unpack-operator-in-python/